# Google maps zoning data

Tags: google-maps, localization, maps

I would like to check if a certain street is in a residential or businesses area. 
Is there anyway to get this data using Google maps service?

or any other service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get this information with the GIS department of each city or district prefecture.
I don't believe Google has this information.

Comment: I'm looking for a service which I can query this data. do you think that's exist?

Comment: I don't think that there is any place that centralizes this kind of information a redistributes it. And the providers don't usually provide this data as a service. They will sell you a SHP file with the information you need.

Comment: @shaimagz My guesses aren't completely random. I worked once with such type of data.